# python mechanize forms()

Tags: python, mechanize-python

For this code:

```py
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("https://www.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover")
for i in bt.forms():
    print i
```

the result is:

```html
<POST https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1 application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(lsd=AVrIS_yx) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(email=)>
  <PasswordControl(pass=)>
  <SubmitControl(<None>=طھط³ط¬ظٹظ„ ط§ظ„ط¯ط®ظˆظ„) (readonly)>
  <CheckboxControl(persistent=[1])>
  <HiddenControl(default_persistent=0) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(timezone=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(lgnrnd=004018_suds) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(lgnjs=n) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(locale=ar_AR) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(next=https://www.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover) (readonly)>>
<POST https://www.facebook.com/ajax/login/help/identify.php?ctx=recover application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(lsd=AVrIS_yx) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(email=)>
  <SubmitControl(did_submit=ط¨ط­ط«) (readonly)>>
```

How can I select the second post, which has only one parameter (`email`), and submit it?

Comment: You may get more answers if you turn the title into a question - ie : How can I select a form with python-mechanize? Also - both to encourage more answers, and to assist yourself in finding the problem - try reducing to a simpler one - create the simplest html page with examples of the structure you would like to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Select it using `select_form()`:

```
br.select_form(nr=1)
br.form['email'] = 'email here'
req = br.submit()
```

Important note: be careful not to violate [Facebook Web-scraping Terms](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php).

Answer (score 0):

when i do this

```py
br.select_form(nr=1)
br.form['email'] = 'email'
br.submit()
br.response().read()
```

the response is be empty